# Empty WebGL context uses a lot of memory

Tags: memory, opengl-es, html5-canvas, webgl

For example, for my 940M video card, the canvas created with the following code takes 500 MB of video memory

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('webgl');
c.width = c.height = 4096;
```

At the same time, the OpenGL context of the same sizes uses only 100 MB of video memory:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
int s = 4096;
glutInitWindowSize(s, s);
glutCreateWindow("Hello world :D");
```

Why does the WebGL use so much memory? Is it possible to reduce the amount of used memory for the same sizes of the context?

Comment: how are you measuring that?

Comment: @LJᛃ using the Task Manager in the Opera, or NVidia X Server Settings in the Ubuntu

Comment: Well getting a default WebGL context like you do has antialiasing, alpha channel, depth buffer and (afaik) double buffering enabled, your glut setup code has none of that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As LJ pointed out, canvas is double buffered, antialiased, has alpha and a depth buffer by default. You made the canvas 4096 x 4096 so that's

```
16meg * 4 (RGBA) or 64meg for one buffer
```

You get that times at least 4

```
front buffer = 1
antialiased backbuffer = 2 to 16
depth buffer = 1
```

So that's 256meg to 1152meg depending on what the browser picks for antialiasing.

In answer to your question you can try to not ask for a depth buffer, alpha buffer and/or antialiasing

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('webgl', { alpha: false, depth: false, antialias: false});
c.width = c.height = 4096;
```

Whether the browser actually doesn't allocate an alpha channel or does but just ignores it is up to the browser and driver. Whether it will actually not allocate a depth buffer is also up to the browser. Passing `antialias: false` should at least make the 2nd buffer 1x instead of 2x to 16x.

Comment: Thank you so much. Context without depth, alpha and anti-aliasing does take up much less memory